# Jetpack compose bottom sheet in an existing activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

we have an existing activity written as traditional view. I'd like to create a new compose-based activity that I display on top of that existing activity so that the first activity's content is visible beneath the bottom sheet.

We have a working implementation as view, but the challenge is to use compose. The only thing I get to work is opening a new activity with the bottom sheet on top - but in this case the first activity is covered by the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to add a compose bottom sheet on top of a view, so I created a new activity with a ModalBottomSheet on top, another solution would be to recreate the view in compose and add a BottomSheetScaffold if the content of the original view should still be modified/accessible.

Comment: I am stuck at the same problem , I just need a bottom sheet to pop up over my existing activity , I do not want the background that comes with it. Did you find any relevant solution ? I cannot afford to implement the above mentioned solution.

Comment: Hi Saneen, unfortunately I did not find any other way to blend a bottom sheet above the existing activity.

Comment: Hey padmalcom . thank you for your response . I actually digged a bit too much and found a solution. 
I am not sure , if it would work for your case , I'll just add the solution and its reference to it here as an answer.
Again , thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The Idea is to extract the rootView of the activity as ViewGroup.

```
val viewGroup = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup
```

And add the bottomSheet as ComposeView to this viewGroup , which makes sure that it is displayed on top of any activity.

```
viewGroup.addView(
        ComposeView(viewGroup.context).apply {
            setContent {
                ModalBottomSheetLayout()
            }
        }
    )
```

for more reference , checkout the blog.

https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-bottom-sheet-over-android-view-using-kotlin-extension-7fecfa8fe369